# Using NumberPicker in Android 3

Tags: android, user-interface, android-widget

I'm trying to use the NumberPicker widget in Android 3.1. I figure it is now a standard widget, part of a public API, and not an internal widget anymore.
However, it doesn't work. I can see a textEdit with "0" in it, but there are no buttons, I can't scroll it, and I can't enter a new number with keyboard, either.

### Update:

Here's the xml I used for testing:

```
    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

By saying doesn't work I mean this: it doesn't have arrows displayed (see [the screenshot](http://img508.imageshack.us/img508/5110/10121048.png)), and on emulator the keyboard doesn't show up. On a real device it does, but I can't type in the text, I can only erase it.

Any suggestions? I really hate to write my own widget when there is a standard one.

Comment: Describe "it doesn't work". How are you using it? Post some code.

Comment: Good point, updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set the values that are possible in the NumberPicker via

[setMaxValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setMaxValue%28int%29) [setMinValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setMinValue%28int%29) or [setDisplayedValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setDisplayedValues%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

maybe the NumberPicker is not working if it doesn't know which values to display.